# Compression of small string

Tags: c#, compression

I have data 0f 340 bytes in string mostly consists of signs and numbers like "føàA¹º@ƒUë5§Ž§"
I want to compress into 250 or less bytes to save it on my RFID card.
As this data is related to finger print temp. I want lossless compression.
So is there any algorithm which i can implement in C# to compress it?

Comment: Have you tried basic Huffman compression? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding. The space requirements for the decompression table would probably outweight any space savings, though.

Comment: Compression algorithms don't have a knob that lets you say "I want *this* many bytes".  If that existed then of course everybody would set it to "1 byte".  Compressing a small number of bytes like this is quite difficult.  More to the point, it is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is strictly numbers and signs, I highly recommend changing the numbers into int based values. eg:

+12939272-23923+927392

can be compress into 3 piece of 32-bit integers, which is 22 bytes => 16 bytes. Picking the right integer size (whether 32-bit, 24-bit, 16-bit) should help.

If the integer size varies greatly, you could possibly use 8-bit to begin and use the value 255 to specify that the next 8-bit becomes the 8 more significant bits of the integer, making it 15-bit.

alternatively, you could identify the most significant character and assign 0 for it. the second most significant character gets 10, and the third 110. This is a very crude compression, but if you data is very limited, this might just do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other information you know about your string? For instance does it contain certain characters more often than others? Does it contain all 255 characters or just a subset of them?

If so, huffman encoding may help you, see [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Huffman_algorithm.aspx) or [this other link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/HuffManSample.aspx) for implementations in C#.

To be honest it just depends on how your input string looks like. What I'd do is try the using rar, zip, 7zip (LZMA) *with very small dictionary sizes* (otherwise they'll just use up too much space for preprocessed information) and see how big the raw compressed file they produce is (will probably have to use their libraries in order to make them strip headers to conserve space). If any of them produce a file under 250b, then find the c# library for it and there you go.